# open 100 files in vim

Tags: linux, vim, file-io, grep

I need to grep to tons (10k+) of files for specific words. 
now that returns a list of files that i also need to grep for another word.

i found on that grep can do this so i use:

```
grep -rl word1 *
```

which returns the list of files i want to check. 
now from these files (100+), i need to grep another word. so i have to do another grep

```
vim `grep word2 `grep -rl word1 *``
```

but that hangs, and it does not do anything,

why?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Because you have a double **`**, you need to use the `$()`

```
vi `grep -l 'word2' $(grep -rl 'word1' *)`
```

Or you can use nested `$(...)` (like goblar mentioned)

```
vi $(grep -l 'word2' $(grep -rl 'word1' *))
```

Answer (score 20):

```
grep -rl 'word1' | xargs grep -l 'word2' | xargs vi
```

is another option.